# Create XML with Multiple Same-Tag Children

Tags: chilkat, chilkat-xml

I will not describe my xml structure, I have prepared an example for reproduction.
Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<A>
    <B>b</B>
    <C>c1</C>
    <C>c2</C>
</A>
```

Code:

```
Set xml = CreateObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.Xml")
xml.Tag = "A"
xml.UpdateChildContent "B", "b"
xml.UpdateChildContent "C", "c1"
xml.UpdateChildContent "C[1]", "c2"
Debug.Print xml.getxml
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<A>
    <B>b</B>
    <C>c1</C>
</A>
```

If I change c index from 1 to 2 then get two C nodes. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem should be fixed in the latest version of Chilkat.